# OSD Lyrics on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, notify-osd

Guys how do I install OSD Lyrics on Ubuntu 13.04 ?
I added the repo, but when installing it comes :

```
 Fetched 1,132 kB in 47s (23.8 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/osd-lyrics/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/osd-lyrics/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have Clementine installed, But OSD isn't.
Even when I search in the Dash it doesn't show up

Please help

Comment: it doesn't look like there is a version for raring (https://launchpad.net/~osd-lyrics/+archive/ppa). Have you tried using the quantal version?

Comment: @noosd, Does it fetch any lyric successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/osd-lyrics-ppa-raring.list`

...and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, when you open it, change `raring` to `precise`.

**Example:**
original: `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/osd-lyrics/ppa/ubuntu raring main`
changed: `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/osd-lyrics/ppa/ubuntu precise main`

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and press <kbd>Y</kbd>

now update: `sudo apt-get update`
and install: `sudo apt-get install osdlyrics`

When you think that osdlyrics has been updated, substitute `precise` with `raring` and update again.